# Spring AOP: Advice not called in abstract class

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am trying save some data after and whenever a getResponse() is called from an implementation of class DefaultRequestHandler. But this not work, what am I missing?

```
@Aspect
public abstract class RequestHandler {
   protected ServiceProvider response;
   protected  ServiceProvider request;

    @Pointcut
    public abstract ServiceProvider getResponse();


    @After("com.mypackage.RequestHandler.getResponse()")
    public void save(ServiceProvider request, ServiceProvider response){
       persistence.save(request, response);
 }

}
```

Comment: Your pointcut is empty and why a point cut on the class itself? The aspect shouldn't be on the service but a separate class.

Comment: @M. Deinum Could you explain a bit more? or show the corerct way? I might also consider putting advice right on persistenceService, is that what you meant

Comment: What is it you want? You state that on the invocation of a getResponse you want to invoke the save method. But why on earth is that an `@Aspect`? It should be a service and nothing more. The aspect should be a different class containing the advice and point cut . It should be an execution point cut. You seem to be lacking the basic understanding on how AOP works and how to write aspects.

Comment: @M. Deinum I wouldnt ask if I knew!

Comment: I dont want the implementing classes call save method manually, but it is invoked everytime after the getResponse method is called and data is saved behind scenes

Comment: It is an abstract method you can simply implement that in a base method instead of with an aspect. Also this is going to be problematic because you are trying to access member variables. Although you could hack around this it isn't very pretty nor maintainable. Why not just do that in your base class. When `getResponse` is called, save. Make `getResponse not abstract but implement it, and create a protected `doGetResponse` method which is to be implemented. That way you have it in your class.

Comment: @M. Deinum tnx if you could show this with a sample code, I will accept it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels like you are using a canon to shoot a bug. Just create a base method which first saves and afterwards calls an abstract method. Subclasses need to implement that method.

```
public abstract class DefaultRequestHandler {
    protected ServiceProvider response;
    protected  ServiceProvider request;

    public final ServiceProviderTxn getResponse() {
       ServiceProviderTxn responseTxn = doGetResponse();
       save(request,responseTxn);
       return responseTxn;
    }

    protected abstract ServiceProviderTxn deGetResponse();

    public void save(ServiceProviderTxn request, ServiceProviderTxn response){
        persistenceService.save(request, response);
    }

}
```

A solution without AOP and which will still work. You might want to make the save method also final (or private depending on your needs).